Problems with laravel using blade
My script from the view blade is executing first than my scripts in the layout view
Hi everyone I'm learning to use Laravel and actually I want to use some code javascript in it, I'm using a layout I show you in the next code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>

<body class="bg-slate-900 text-white overflow-hidden">
    <header class="flex flex-row p-8 bg-slate-950">
        <div>
            <h3 class="font-bold text-2xl">@yield('nav-title')</h3>
        </div>

        <nav class="w-full flex flex-row-reverse ">
            @yield('nav-options')
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="flex flex-row">
        <aside class=" bg-slate-950 h-dvh">
            <nav class=" flex flex-col w-40">
                <a href="{{ route('productos.inicio') }}" class=" text-center flex flex-col hover:bg-green-500 p-4 transition-colors"> <i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping text-zinc-50"></i> Productos</a>

                <a href="" class=" text-center flex flex-col hover:bg-blue-500 p-4 transition-colors"> <i class="fa-solid fa-book-open"></i>Categorias</a>

                <a href="" class=" text-center flex flex-col hover:bg-yellow-500 p-4 transition-colors"> <i class="fa-solid fa-wallet"></i>Ventas</a>
                <a href=""></a>
            </nav>
        </aside>
        <main class=" m-8 w-full max-h-full overflow-auto">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer>
        @yield('footer-content')
    </footer>

    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
    <script>
        let token;
        //Obtener token para realizar las solicitudes post
        fetch('one_fetch_petition')
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Error en la solicitud: ' + response.status);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                // Éxito, manejar la respuesta JSON
                token = data.token;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Si no se obtuvo resultado el token será 0
                token = 0;
                console.log("Error al hacer la petición del token: " + error);
            });
    </script>
    @stack('scripts')
</body>

</html>


The problem is, when I use it another view using this layout it chargues first the script in that view when I think it should be reverse I mean, the first script charged should be from the layout and I can't use code from app.js for that problem :(
I'll adjunt a picture showing that I want to express
enter image description here

How are you including the scripts in your other view?

Can you try to place @vite('resources/js/app.js') in the head where the @vite('resources/css/app.css') is located?
FYI u can use a 1 liner for this:
@vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'])
